# setState not rendering the change immediately but rather after some other state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am learning React following this [video](https://youtu.be/w7ejDZ8SWv8), and while adding a new object to the state array containing all the tasks in this to-do list app changes are not getting immediately rendered but rather after some other state change when I write a different version of what I understand to be doing the same stuff from the video but if I exactly write video's version then its getting rendered immediately.

Inside App.js :

```js
 let initialTasks = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Doctor's Appointment",
      date: "10th Feb, 2023",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "College Fest",
      date: "18th Feb, 2023",
      reminder: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Mid-Semester exams",
      date: "21th Feb, 2023",
      reminder: true,
    },
  ];

  let [tasks, setTasks] = useState(initialTasks);
  let [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
```

My version of addTask function:

```js
  const addTask = (task) => {
    let tempTasks = tasks;
    tempTasks.push({ id: 10, ...task });
    setTasks(tempTasks);
  };
```

Working version from the video:

```js
  const addTask = (task) => {
    const newTask = { id: 10, ...task };
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  };
```

In my version the task state is getting updated but is not rendering immediately but renders after showForm state changes. Any help is appreciated.

Link to GitHub repo if needed: https://github.com/ayush0402/react-tasker

Comment: your 'version' mutates the state but passes the same array reference to `setTasks` which React will ignore. You need to pass a new array reference (and not mutate the existing state) as indicated by the tutorial's version. To make your version work with `push()` you would need to first clone the `tasks` array, `let tempTasks = [...tasks];` and then proceed as you are.

Comment: covered fully in the docs: [React: Updating Arrays in State](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state)

Answer (score 1):

Let's Make It Simple

```
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Doctor's Appointment",
      date: "10th Feb, 2023",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "College Fest",
      date: "18th Feb, 2023",
      reminder: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Mid-Semester exams",
      date: "21th Feb, 2023",
      reminder: true,
    },
  ]);

  const addTask = (task) => {
   // here we are getting prev tasks and merging it with given task in array
    setTasks([...tasks, task]);
  };

  console.log("Added Task",tasks);
```

Paste Above Code in Your File and Try It Will Work.

Answer (score 0):

Your version with comments:

```js
const addTask = (task) => {
  let tempTasks = tasks; // tempTasks takes memory reference of tasks
  tempTasks.push({ id: 10, ...task }); // adds object
  setTasks(tempTasks); // update is not performed because memory reference never changed
};
```

Working version with comments **(use this version)**:

```js
const addTask = (task) => {
  const newTask = { id: 10, ...task }; // create new object
  setTasks([...tasks, newTask]); // new memory reference is created because of the spread operator
};
```

Combining them:

```js
const addTask = (task) => {
  let tempTasks = tasks; // tempTasks takes memory reference of tasks, but also mutates the state and is incorrect
  tempTasks.push({ id: 10, ...task }); // adds object
  setTasks([...tempTasks]); // update is performed because spread operator creates new reference
};
```

I hope this helps!

Edit:

As pilchard mentioned, the combination I've exemplified above is incorrect because it mutates the state (`tempTasks` is a reference to `tasks`) and even though in most scenarios it might work fine, it can sometimes cause unexpected behaviour. Therefore, stick to the working version.

Comment: Your combination mutates the existing state, clone before pushing not after. `let tempTasks = [...tasks];` ... `setTasks(tempTasks);`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please read the comments. First we clone and have the same reference, we push thus mutating the state but makes no difference in rendering, lastly we update the state using spread operator to create a new reference.

Comment: Mutating state should be avoided regardless of rendering status, simply create a new reference before pushing.

Comment: I see what you mean. I agree.